# Hierarchical mutex locks in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, mutex

I want to be able to lock based on a filesystem hierarchy.  For example:

Thread 1:

```
lock("/");
doStuff();
unlock();
```

Thread 2:

```
lock("/sub/foo");
doStuff();
unlock();
```

Thread 3:

```
lock("/sub/bar");
doStuff();
unlock();
```

If Thread 1 acquires the lock first then threads 2 and 3 will be blocked until Thread 1 unlocks.  However, if Thread 2 acquires the lock first, then Thread 3 should be able to execute at the same time as Thread 2.  The general rule is that if there is a lock on a parent directory, then the thread must block.

Does Java have anything built-in that can help solve this?  I want to avoid storing a lock per directory because there will be hundreds of thousands of directories.

Comment: +1 for a seriously interesting question.  Is the directory structure specified in advance, or can "files" be created ad-hoc?  Also, what is the priority system if one thread wants to get the root directory while a lot of other threads all try to get individual files?  Does the thread that wants the root just starve, or is there some sort of guarantee you have in mind?

Comment: I assume that if Thread 2 acquires the lock, Thread 1 should block, right?

Comment: Part of the motivation behind this is to modify the file system, so the paths would be constantly changing.  I'm not sure how to handle thread starvation... that's something I haven't really considered.  I suppose a read/write lock mechanism might get close to solving this and be able to handle not starving threads.

Comment: Can you maybe give more details of what the app, and doStuff(), does?  What happens with the folders?  Is the entire tree being traversed and err.. 'stuffed'?

Comment: in my application, doStuff() might remove the directory/file or might just modify that directory by adding some more directories/files to it.

Comment: I might be wrong but it seems to me that if you want to acquire the lock for `/foo/bar`, you need to lock `/` first, then '/foo' and then '/foo/bar'.

Comment: I'm not convinced yet that a solution for modifying the tree in a general way using only hard-locks, as suggested by the OP, is realistic, (or even provable deadlock-free).  If I was to attempt something like it seems as though the OP wants, I would assemble a completely seperate folder tree until done, then delete the 'old' tree and rename the new tree.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd store the directory paths in a tree like this:

```
- /
 - sub
  - foo
  - bar
```

Whenever you need to lock anything in that tree you go down from the root and acquire a read-lock on everything except the target node itself. The target node gets a write lock.

This scheme guarantees you deadlock-freedom and stability of the relevant parts of the tree.

I don't see a particular problem storing hundreds of thousands of locks. This is probably going to waste maybe 100 bytes of RAM per lock. But it simplifies the architecture. Did you measure if it actually is a problem?

As an alternative you can have a map from path to lock. All operations on that dictionary must be synchronized by callers. This allows you to lazily initialize locks. You can also periodically garbage-collect unused locks by first taking a write-lock on the root which quiesces all operations. Once everything is quiet you discard all non-root locks.

Comment: Cool approach.  I think that could work.  If I have to store a lock per directory, then so be it.  I was just trying to avoid it if possible.

Comment: This is how databases do their locking. They lock the B-tree path from the root down to the leaf pages.

Comment: This looks good. I'd go with a `java.util.ConcurrentHashMap` for best performance and I'd map it as `<File, ReadWriteLock>`. I'd also use `File file = new File(stringPath).getCanonicalFile()` to guarantee uniqueness. The logic should then be fairly clear given lazy lock creation and separate locking for read and write.

Comment: @ScottFrazer & usr : don't forget to lock (/take care of) both the canonical and absolute path : you wouldn't want to forget a symlink. (Hardlink are also a problem but will be much harder to discover from Java)

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more performant solution, but here's how I would start.

I would create a shared TreeAccess object, with a `lock(path)` and an `unlock(path)` method. This method would have to enter a synchronized block which would loop until the path is available. At each iteration, if not available, it would check if the path is available, and if not, `wait()` until some other thread calls `notifyAll()`. If the path is available, then it would proceed, and when done, call the unlock() method which would `notifyAll()`.

Before proceeding, you have to store the locked path into some data structure. And before notifying, you have to remove the unlocked path from this data structure. To check if a path is available, you need to find if there exist some path in this data structure that is equal or is an ancestor of the path you want to lock.

```
public void lock(String path) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        while (!available(path)) {
            lock.wait();
        }
        lockedPaths.add(path);
    }
}

public void unlock(String path) {
    synchronized (lock) {
        lockedPaths.remove(path);
        lock.notifAll();
    }
}

private boolean available(String path) {
    for (String lockedPath : lockedPaths) {
        if (isParentOrEqual(lockedPath, path) { // this method is left as an exercise
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```